# choosing table design for database performance

Tags: sql-server, database

I am developing a Job application which executes multiple parallel jobs. Every job will pull data from third party source and process. Minimum records are 100,000. So i am creating new table for each job (like Job123. 123 is jobId) and processing it. When job starts it will clear old records and get new records and process. Now the problem is I have 1000 jobs and the DB has 1000 tables. The DB size is drastically increased due to lots of tables.

My question is whether it is ok to create new table for each job. or have only one table called Job and have column jobId, then enter data and process it. Only problem is every job will have 100,000+ records. If we have only one table, whether DB performance will be affected?

Please let me know which approach is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create all those tables! Even though it might work, there's a huge performance hit.

Having a big table is fine, that's what databases are for. But...I suspect that you don't need 100 million *persistent* records, do you? It looks like you only process one Job at a time, but it's unclear.

**Edit**

The database will grow to the largest size needed, but the space from deleted records is reused. If you add 100k records and delete them, over and over, the database won't keep growing. But even after the delete it will take up as much space as 100k records.

Comment: Yes. Its temporary only. But some times job will be incomplete, that time I will store data, so job will recontinue from where it is left. <br> If we keep on add & delete the DB size will increase rite? How we can automate this shrinking?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a single large table for all jobs. There should be one table for each kind of thing, not one table for each thing.

If you make the Job ID the first field in the clustered index, SQL Server will use a b-tree index to determine the physical order of data in the table. In principle, the data will automatically be physically grouped by Job ID due to the physical sort order. This may not stay strictly true forever due to fragmentation, but that would affect a multiple table design as well.

The performance impact of making the Job ID the first key field of a large table should be negligible for single-job operations as opposed to having a separate table for each job.

Also, a single large table will generally be more space efficient than multiple tables for the same amount of total data. This will improve performance by reducing pressure on the cache.